# How to create VFAT formatted 256MB disk image that can be used in Virtualbox?

Tags: usb, virtualbox, virtual-machine, usb-flash-drive, fat32

Trying to replicate a predefined process used for Linux OS installation on bare-metal servers, to VMs (on Oracle Virtualbox).

The process of Linux OS installation uses the OS distribution (RHEL 7) DVD image and a USB pen-drive containing kickstart file (to be used by Anaconda for automating the Linux OS installation) plus some specific additional proprietary software. This is legacy software and I am not at liberty to modify the installation procedure.

What I am trying to figure out is, how do perform the equivalent step for VM (Oracle Virtualbox), hopefully without having to use real physical USB pen-drive. The host OS in my case being Windows 10 Enterprise edition.

Is there a way that I could create a disk image file in Windows 10, containing the contents of the expected USB pendrive (256MB one, with FAT32 formatting, and a very specific **disk-label**) which can then be somehow mounted in the VM where it is visible just like a USB pendrive would be to the Linux OS, as in case of a physical server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways, including:

- Create a VHD format image using Windows 10 built-in tools (diskmgmt.msc → Action → Create VHD). Attach it as a virtual disk on the host Windows system. Use diskmgmt to initialize and format it, then detach it from the host, and add it to the RHEL installation VM. (VirtualBox supports VHD images, although not VHDX.)
- Create a standard VirtualBox disk image using VBox's "Virtual Media Manager". Attach it to an *already installed* VM with your OS of choice (be it Linux or Windows), and use that VM to partition and format the image. Detach it from this VM and attach to the RHEL installation VM.

Comment: Thanks. While with diskmgmt tool I am able to create a VHD disk, I see no option to add partition, format it as FAT32 and add a specific disk label to it ? At least from withint diskmgmt tool, I don't see an obvious way to do those.

Comment: The procedure is the same as with a new completely blank disk. Within diskmgmt, you may first need to right-click the whole disk (e.g. "Disk 3" in the bottom panel) and select "Initialize Disk". (USB sticks are typically sold already initialized with MBR.) Once the disk is initialized (has a partition table), you'll be able to right-click the unallocated area and select "New Simple Volume". The volume creation 'wizard' will add a partition and even offer to format it as FAT32.

Comment: Thanks, silly of me not to have tried the "New Simple Volume" wizard.